# Converting the number of days in a month in Python?

Tags: python, date, calendar

New to Python, and I'm writing a program that has the user enter the month (in terms of a number, NOT the word - e.g. "3" not "March"), and the year (as in "2014"). I want the program to display the number of days in the month entered and the year. So if the user enters month 3 and the year 2005, it should display:

March 2005 has 31 days.

Here's my code:

```
def enteredMonth():
    month = int(input("Enter a month in terms of a number: "))
    return month

def enteredYear():
    year = int(input("Enter a year: "))
    return int(year)

def leapYear(year):
    if year % 4 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def numberOfDays(month):
    if enteredMonth() == 1:
        month = "January"
        print ("31")
    elif enteredMonth() == 2:
        month = "February"
        print ("28")
    elif enteredMonth() == 2 and leapYear() == true:
        month = "February"
        print ("29")
    elif enteredMonth() == 3:
        month = "March"
        print ("31")
    elif enteredMonth() == 4:
        month = "April"
        print ("30")
    elif enteredMonth() == 5:
        month = "May"
        print ("31")
    elif enteredMonth() == 6:
        month = "June"
        print ("30")
    elif enteredMonth() == 7:
        month = "July"
        print ("31")
    elif enteredMonth() == 8:
        month = "August"
        print ("31")
    elif enteredMonth() == 9:
        month = "September"
        print ("30")
    elif enteredMonth() == 10:
        month = "October"
        print ("31")
    elif enteredMonth() == 11:
        month = "November"
        print ("30")
    elif enteredMonth() == 12:
        month = "December"
        print ("31")
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid month")

def main():
   enteredMonth()
   enteredYear()
   leapYear(year)
   numberOfDays(month)
   print(month, enteredYear(), "has", numberOfDays(month) , "days")

if __name__ == '__main__': 
   main()
```

The problem is that instead of getting the proper format, I'm getting something like:

3 2005 has None days.

Please help! I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't disagree with YS-L's answer. I'm submitting one to show with better formatting what I mean.

```
def enteredMonth():
    month = int(input("Enter a month in terms of a number: "))
    return month

def enteredYear():
    year = int(input("Enter a year: "))
    return int(year)

def leapYear(year):
    if year % 4 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def numberOfDays(month):
    if month == 1:
        return 31
    elif month == 2:
        return 28
    # etc. Actually, the Pythonic implementation would be to use a dict
    # that maps month numbers to their usual number of days.

def main():
   month = enteredMonth()
   year = enteredYear()
   is_leapyear = leapYear(year)
   number_of_days = numberOfDays(month)
   print(month, year, "has", number_of_days, "days")

if __name__ == '__main__': 
   main()
```

This has obvious problems - for example, the leap year adjustment never happens. But it demonstrates how to capture return values from functions, which I think is the main point you're struggling with.

As a more advanced topic, here's how I'd do this using the `datetime` built in library:

```
import datetime

def enteredMonth():
    month = int(input("Enter a month in terms of a number: "))
    return month

def enteredYear():
    year = int(input("Enter a year: "))
    return year

def numberOfDays(year, month):
    first_of_entered_month = datetime.date(year, month, 1)
    someday_next_month = first_of_entered_month + datetime.timedelta(days=31)
    first_of_next_month = someday_next_month.replace(day=1)
    last_of_entered_month = first_of_next_month - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return last_of_entered_month.day

def main():
    month = enteredMonth()
    year = enteredYear()
    number_of_days = numberOfDays(year, month)
    pretty_month_year = datetime.date(year, month, 1).strftime('%B %Y')
    print(pretty_month_year, "has", number_of_days, "days")
```

Comment: So when I add the adjustments, and I test it with month 3 and year 2005, I get an incorrect return of 3 2005 has 28 days?

Comment: Check your month argument handling is all I can say to that - it should parrot back the number of days you return from `numberOfDays` for that month number.

Comment: So using datetime, how would I display the actual month name? So instead of 3 2005 has 31 days, have it display March 2005 has 31 days?

Comment: For that you'd use `strftime`: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior - I'll edit in an example. Although I must admit that I don't work much with Python 3 so I might have `print()`'s behavior slightly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
################################################################
# OR Another way to achieve same thing
def numberOfDays(month, year):
    daysInMonths = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    if month > len(daysInMonths) or year < 0 or month < 0:
        return "Please enter a valid month/year"

    # Here, only divisible by 4 as leap-year but there are many 
    # more conditions for a leap year which you can add in expression
    return daysInMonths[month-1] + int((year % 4) == 0 and month == 2)

def main():
   year = int(input("Enter a year: "))
   month = int(input("Enter a month in terms of a number: "))
   print(month, year, "has", numberOfDays(month, year) , "days")

if __name__ == '__main__': 
   main()

################################################################
# OR using standard library
from calendar import monthrange

def main():
   year = int(input("Enter a year: "))
   month = int(input("Enter a month in terms of a number: "))
   if year < 0 or month < 0:
    print "Pleae enter a valid month/year"
    return
   print(month, year, "has", monthrange(year, month)[1] , "days")

if __name__ == '__main__': 
   main()
```

Comment: You over simplified the leap year rule.  It's a leap year if `(year % 400 == 0) or ((year % 4) == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 ))`.  Note, 2000 and 2400 are leap years in the Gregorian calendar, while 1700, 1800, 1900, 2100 are not leap years.

Comment: I saw it coming. :) You are absolutely right but to i didn't want to bombard user3105664 with too many changes. Let me put a comment there.

Comment: That kind of complication is why I generally favor using a standard library. Even if the standard library is wrong it's at least wrong consistently.

Comment: I agree, Peter DeGlopper!

Answer (score 1):

Inside the function `numberOfDays()`, you need to return the number of days, instead of just printing it. As it returns nothing, it prints `None` in `main()`. I.e. You need to have this line in `numberOfDays()`:

```
return num_days
```

where `num_days` is set as the number of days in the given month. In fact `numberOfDays()` shouldn't event print anything at all. *Just* return the number of days is all it needs to do.

Also, why do you need to call so many `enteredMonth()` inside `numberOfDays()`? You can simply check the input argument `month`.

Inside `main()`, `enteredMonth()` and `enteredYear()` will not set any variable. You need to do something like `month = enteredMonth()`.

Comment: But what do I return in numberOfDays?

Comment: In general you want to capture the return values of your functions to local variables - eg `month = enteredMonth()`. Then in `numberOfDays` you want to look at the `month` parameter that you passed in, not another call to `enteredMonth()`. If you're doing this for real use rather than as a learning exercise you might also consider using the `datetime` built in library rather than trying to calculate leap years on your own (a notoriously easy subject to get wrong) but that's a bit more advanced.

Comment: Any chance you can edit my code so it'll be easier to see what you mean?

Comment: So then in my main(), I would say: print(month, enteredYear(), "has", numberOfDays(), "days")?